# Mysql manual autoincrement concurrent connections proof

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions

I have an invoices table (innoDB) in which i need to set manually the progressive number for the next invoice. My code now is

```
SELECT MAX(invoice_n) FROM invoices WHERE invoice_y = 2013
```

and then regulary save the record putting the new invoice_n = max + 1. I have an index UNIQUE on invoice_n-invoice_y and I'm logging db errors, so I see that sometimes I have duplicate key entry errors, beacuse I have hundreds of different users connected. I put the code in a loop that continues until the invoice is generated, but i think there can be a more elegant solution, especially using transactions. I read a bit but I can't understand how can I achive my result with transactions.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ["AUTO_INCREMENT"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) in your column definition. You will see some gaps between numbers if the insertion fails.

Another alternative is creating a table with the last index per year (see comments) and follow the next steps:

1. Begin a transaction
2. Select for update last index per row and increment in one
3. Insert the new invoice
4. Commit your transaction

Some links:

- [See MySQL (InnoDB) transaction model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html)
- [Locking example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/innodb-row-locking-how-to-implement)

Another one, you could use an "optimistic approach" and repeat the select and the insert if it fails because a duplicate key.

I hope this helps you, any comment is welcome!

Comment: I cannot use auto increment because I have invoice #1 for 2012, and #1 for 2013.

Comment: I added another alternative, see if it helps.

Comment: Does MySQL has concurrent control on generating auto increment key? If not, this answer might has problem. Can  anyone answer my question?

Comment: It depends on the engine. Innodb https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html